# Not able to play flv video in ipad /iphone in safari web-browser, any reason?

Tags: iphone

Not able to play flv video in ipad /iphone in safari web-browser, any reason ??
However, i can play same video in mac system (in safari web-browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An flv file is a Flash Video file. iOS devices do not have a Flash player (and probably never will). It works in your desktop browsers because they have a Flash plugin installed.

You'll have to convert your video file to something that iOS devices can digest (.mp4).

Answer (score 1):

iPhone or iPod touch can't play flv videos on the web because they haven't Flash Player.

Answer (score 1):

FLV is a flash video and the iPad and iPhone don't support flash. You're able to play it in Safari because you have the flash plugin installed.